# Can I drop the $f(0) = 0$ condition and still get the same result?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is twice-differentiable, convex and satisfy $f(0) = 0$ and
$$\lim_{|x|\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{|x|} = +\infty. \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Define $g: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(p) = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}}(\langle x, p \rangle -f(x))$. I want to prove that the supremum is actually a maximum or, in other words, it is attained at some point $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$.

My proof is the following. By (\ref{1}), given $M > 0$ there exists $N > 0$ such that $f(x) > M|x|$ whenever $|x| > N$. For $p$ fixed, take $M = |p|$ and the corresponding $N$. Let $B_{N} =\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: |x| \le N\}$. If $x \in B_{N}^{c}$ then $|x| > N$, so we obtain:
$$\langle x, p \rangle -f(x) \le |x||p|-f(x) < 0.$$
On the other hand, $B_{N}$ is compact so $\langle x,p\rangle - f(x)$ attains a maximum on this domain. Because $f(0) = 0$, this local maximum is also a global maximum.

My question is: can I drop the condition $f(0) = 0$ and still get this result? I mean, if $f(0)$ is arbitrary, can we still guarantee that the supremum in the definition of $g$ is also attained at some point?

Comment: Yes, just define $h(x)=f(x)-f(0)$ and repeat the proof on $h$.

Comment: Also, your proof only uses the fact that $f$ is continuous. Differentiability and convexity are not needed.